# using Regular Expression in Group by Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, group-by

I have a table 'items'

```
Item_Code             |Rate  |Quantity
--------------------------------------
JOGGER-POWER-BLACK    |699   |5
JOGGER-POWER-WHITE    |599   |8    
JOGGER-PLAZA-WHITE    |1199  |2
SLEEPER-PLAZA-BLACK   |699   |6
SLEEPER-POWER-BLACK   |499   |5
```

I want to Group by Part1-%-Part3 of Item_Code like following which is just idea

```
select (part1 and part3 of Item_Code) as 'Category-Color',sum(Quantity)
as Quantity group by (part1 and part3 of Item_Code)
```

By Parts I mean looking Item_Code in terms of Hyphen

**Desired Output**

```
Category-Color|Quantity
-------------------
JOGGER-BLACK  |5
JOGGER-WHITE  |10
SLEEPER-BLACK |11
```

"regular expressions in group by clause","group by with regular expression". Google/Bing giving nothing relevant

I am unable to understand whether database developers are not required to  provide this feature or how they do it. I am required such grouping by the Store owner. e.g Category (Part1) wise Sum of quantities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item_Code, '-', 1), '-', 
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item_Code, '-', -1)) AS Category_Color,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM items
GROUP BY 1;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0fc7/2)

Comment: How should I edit my question title. So it would be better helpful later for the viewers. What you think with what words should i had searched it?

Comment: I think it's okay. Probably you don't need to change it.

Comment: O my God. That's the way @Omesh. Is there something else to pay more? as just voting and accepting seems to me a little especially for your effort of demo along with solution.

Comment: No need my dear friend, as this site is a free learning site for all! Cheers!